# Creating a program to plot excel data in python using input() to choose file

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to create a program where I input the filename of the Excel file (using pandas) and it will plot the data from this file. How do I get pandas.read_excel(file path) to work with the input() function?

Comment: You could consider using [`tkinter.filedialogue.askopenfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile)

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
input('Write file path')
pandas.read_excel(file path)
```